# Создание коллекции объектов нескольких указанных типов в C#

Tags: ооп, .net, c#

Можно ли создать одну коллекцию IEnumerable или Dictionary для объектов определенного класса и его потомков в C#?

Просто использовать тип "object" и приведение типов чревато возникновением ошибок и потерей данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, если Вы создаёте коллекцию элементов определённого типа, то все его подтипы будут поддерживаться автоматически. В выходных позициях, конечно же, может потребоваться приведение.

Comment: Я же могу использовать для приведения поле класса-родителя?

Comment: Чо?